# “possible duplicate” comment should be re-added if it's been deleted

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

Background: when I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243181/removing-replacing-x201d-from-string), it had 2 votes to close as duplicate, but it didn't have the usual automatically-generated comment. What happened was that [the first closer changed his mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93893/possible-duplicate-comment-not-added-on-a-particular-question/93894#93894) and deleted the automatic comment.

In this situation, when a second closer comes along and also decides to close as duplicate, a new comment should be generated. Otherwise the potential duplicate isn't visible until the question is closed, which often means wasted time as people redo the work of answering the question.

Comment: Probably that the comment was removed. Can't say why it wasn't readded though.

Comment: I noticed that when the proposed dupe is already in the Linked list the comment is not added. I think, I'm not going to experiment.

Answer (score 3):

I suggested the duplicate, but on closer look, found that the original doesn't really answer the question. I then removed the comment (in hindsight, wrongly - the original question *is* better).

Removed "possible duplicate" comments do not get replaced if someone else votes for the same duplicate.

Comment: I see. If you thought it wasn't a duplicate after all, it would have been better to replace the comment with “this is related but not a duplicate: <link>”. But the question really is a duplicate, even if the old question hadn't been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

You can always post a comment yourself. Does it really need to be automatic when somebody already changed his mind on it?

Besides that, editing the comment to "related to", as you already pointed out, might be a better option in borderline cases.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a fallback? If first voter removed it, it should fall to the second, no?