# Auto comment for possible duplicate is not added

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“possible duplicate” comment should be re-added if it’s been deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93893/possible-duplicate-comment-should-be-re-added-if-its-been-deleted)

I voted to close [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164894/152859) as duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/152859).

The vote is now there, however the expected "possible duplicate of..." comment was never added.

By the time I voted to close, there was no link whatsoever to the dupe question, unless it's in a deleted comment I can't see. (Now there is but it was posted after my vote)

My only assumption as this point is that it's due to the question being migrated but it might also be "global" bug.

Comment: @Martijn how can you see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone *else* had flagged that post as a possible duplicate already, but has since deleted their comment. I guess they changed their mind.

As for how I know that: I don't have special deleted comment viewing powers. You can see I commented on that post too, and the 'dupe' comment came right after mine until it was deleted. I guess the voter (can't recall whom) felt that my comment cast enough doubt on that question being a dupe.

Comment: *"I don't have special deleted comment viewing powers"*....nice save

Comment: Hmm.. I was pretty sure my vote was the first but of course don't have tools to prove this. Need a mod to confirm! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: if someone without voting privs *flags* instead, the comment is also generated, but no close vote is counted.

Comment: @Bart: I almost gave that away.. *pfwew*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, didn't know that. Sure about that? (not doubting you! ;))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Let me find that deleted comment that proves my claim for you...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: But yes, I'm sure about that. Take a gander through the SO close vote review queue, you'll sometimes come across a post that is in the queue with 0 votes, a dupe comment and you'll be the first to vote. That's a post that was flagged.

Comment: OK, fair enough. :-)

Comment: It wasn't actually a close vote; someone just added a normal comment with a link to that other question (in which case we don't add the autocomment either).

Comment: @balpha: Ah, that was the third option; the rest of what I said still is correct, though? Flagging creates the comment too.

Comment: Yeah, the rest is correct. Well, except that I can't know the motives for deleting the comment :) But it's plausible.