# Duplicate post notice missing the duplicate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, post-notices

Just browsing and came across [a question marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868818/check-if-url-contains-parameters), but the post notice doesn't have a link to the duplicate:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I can spot a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination in the top banner.

Comment: I guess it's because that's one of the old-style duplicates, where the dupe target was edited into the source. It shows in the old notices view.

Comment: The question is an older duplicate, from the time the duplicate target was edited into the question body rather than being displayed as an automatic notice. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306024/377214) for what I mean.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog I don't recall ever seeing that before, I figured the user just put that in there. Regardless, the link to the duplicate quiestion should still live in a canonical place (i.e. the banner.)

Comment: Bug already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337903/273397) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337676/273397) and here is the [initial bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337282/273397) which triggered the currently "fixed" version

Comment: Thanks @Tom I checked but didn't get onto the second page. Now if only there were some way to mark a question as a duplicate of an answer...

Comment: You can still close the question as a dupe and the specific answers are here in the comment section. And @AdamLear can you also please update the state of the two linked answers when you investigate and maybe later fix this issue (i.e. add the status-review tag there as well)? Thank you.

Comment: @AdamLear, reckon you could guess at a timeline for y'all getting to this? The community is capable of adequately handling this themselves by hand if needed - all it takes is someone to craft a SEDE query to find affected questions, and then one willing mod on each affected site to reopen and reclose each of them, of which I doubt there are more than a few hundred across the entire network. We could even script it for them. Should we just go ahead and do that, or wait for the company to solve it on their end?

Answer (score 7):

Back in the day, we didn't track duplicate targets and the links were instead inserted into the post's body. You can see it below the post notice:

> [image]

Reopening/reclosing the question would "fix" this up, but I agree we should perhaps at least change up the copy a bit to make it more clear what's happening in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember ever noticing that before, but it may just stand out more with the new blue boxes on top. If the inserted markup is reasonably consistent, it should be possible to pull the target question out and update the question. Whether you guys want to devote the resources to that is another question.

Comment: I think any question with 50k views should have the duplicate link fixed,    maybe any question with over 5k views.  Even if a CM has to do it all by hand,